# Custom Entity with a uid property

Tags: 7, entities

We seem to be experiencing a very unexpected problem.

We have created a custom entity called feature and it has a uid property. The schema is as follows:

```
$schema['feature'] = array(
  'fields' => array(
    'fid' => array(
      'description' => 'feature id',
      'type' => 'serial',
      'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
    'bundle' => array(
      'description' => 'bundle name',
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => 32,
      'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
    'nid' => array(
      'description' => 'Node ID.',
      'type' => 'int',
      'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
    'tid' => array(
      'description' => 'Taxonomy Term ID.',
      'type' => 'int',
      'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
    'uid' => array(
      'description' => 'User ID.',
      'type' => 'int',
      'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
    'created' => array(
      'description' => 'created timestamp',
      'type' => 'int',
      'not null' => TRUE,
    )
  ),
  'unique keys' => array(
    'primary key' => array('fid'),
    'nid-tid-uid' => array('nid', 'tid'),
  )
);
```

An entity is then picked up with

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'feature')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'disabled')
  ->propertyCondition('tid', $tid)
  ->propertyCondition('nid', $nid)
  ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1));
$result = $query->execute();

if (isset($result['feature'])) {
  $features = entity_load('feature', array(reset($result['feature'])->fid));
  $feature =  reset($features); // $feature here as the wrong uid
}
```

However, no matter what permutation I try, the uid is always set to 1.

The database has the correct information - so the data is being stored correctly.

The entity has views integration and pulling the data in through views works correctly as well.

Outputting the $feature always gives a uid = 1.

I even have traced through the EntityAPIController with little luck.

I tried loading an unrelated entity (Field Collection Item). This entity does *not* have a uid field. However, after entity_load it seems that a uid property is set.

Does this mean that having a uid property on an entity is just not possible? There does not seem to be any documentation to suggest that this is the case though.

I know that I can just rename it to aid or something else but am curious as to the cause here.

Thanks...

Comment: I use `uid` in custom entities all the time, it's definitely not reserved/disallowed or anything like that. Have you implemented a custom controller or are you using `EntityAPIController` straight up?

Comment: a custom controller but it just adds a created field - so nothing exciting... I found another entity which seems to be using a uid field as well - so this seems very strange indeed... :-/

Answer (score 0):

I left it overnight, and by the following day, the issue was gone.... :-/

Comment: Cron likely ran and/or cleared caches.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem on my local machine. So far I tried: `drush cc all`, `drush cron`, restarting mysql, rebooting my computer. Still have the same problem. Next step --- I will leave it overnight and hope that it magically disappears :)

Comment: In the end it was solved by restoring an earlier backup of the database (which was OK for me since it was only a site on my local dev computer)